# How to view mounted CD drive in Solaris 10

Tags: mount, solaris

Say I have a Solaris 10 Virtual machine VM mounted on vmware platform and I only have telnet terminal to connect to it. How do I see if this VM has a CD already mounted?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solaris 10:  Look in `/mnt` directory.

Solaris 11:  Look in `/media` directory.

Btw:  When you say "Telnet" I really hope you mean SSH. Telnet was deprecated many years ago (in any OS) and as far as I remember is no longer installed by default in Solaris.